# Turning a raggedly filled array into heatmap in python

Tags: python

I am working with python and trying to implement a heatmap.  I have data that is being stored into a 2d array.  the array is roughly array[1000][1000] but sometimes the xvalues are greater than 1000.

I am looking to make a heatmap of this array, and I cannot figure out how to do it. I have no idea how to get my data to conform since it is a ragged array not a standard size.

Here is a rough copy of my code I have been attempting

```
sum_data = None
#count = 0
#for in_file in file_values:
print "summing file: data" 
data = []
with open('data', 'r') as in_data:
    for line in in_data:
        line_no_end= line.rstrip('\n')
        list_container = []
        list_container = line_no_end.split(",")
        #print "eachRow: %s" % list_container
        data.append(list_container)
if sum_data == None:
    sum_data = data
else:
    sum_data = [[int(sum_data[y][x]) + int(data[y][x]) for x in range(len(data[y]))] for y in range(len(data))] #makes 2d array from file
```

and then I was trying to get it to conform to this heatmap example

```
heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x,y,bins = 50)
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]
plt.clf()
plt.imshow(heatmap,extent=extent)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('output.png')
```